# Creating partially transparent QMessageBoxes in PyQt5 and Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyqt5, opacity, gnome-3

I'm trying to create an instance of QMessageBox, using methods such as:

```
self.d = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
self.d.setText(text)
self.d.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.d.setStyleSheet("""QMessageBox { background-color: 
                                  rgb(122,122,122, 50) };
                                  """)
```

Where 0.5 is the alpha (i.e. the level of transparency).

No matter what approach I try, I just no change from the default:
[image]

For reference, I'm using:
PyQt5
Arch Linux
Systemd
Gnome-Desktop

Comment: I get the following, and I'm using PyQt5
Arch linux
Systemd
Gnome-Desktop: https://imgur.com/a/dsaPg

Comment: Are you using any varients to my approach? Could I possibly cross check for my own debugging? Thanks @eyllanesc

Comment: Just use your code